# Go over 24 hours in a date?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am working on project (a Google Transit feed) where I am required to provide the times for each stop on a bus route in the following common format: 21:00:00 and so forth.

Problem is, if times continue past midnight for a given trip, they require it to continue the hour counting accordingly. They explain quite specifically that 02:00:00 should become 26:00:00 and 03:45:00 should become 27:45:00 etc.

I am baffled on how to display such with any of the date() or strtotime() functions.

The only thing I can think of in my particular situation would be to function match and replace any strings in my output between 00:00:00 and 04:00:00, as that would clearly mean (again, for me only) that these are trips originating before midnight, but I don't feel that's the correct way.

Comment: So you want do display the time between 00:00 and 04:00 with 24:00 to 28:00 ?

Comment: You can't, because the time 26:35 does not exist anywhere! So you will have to explode it or something and store it as a string.

Comment: +1 and bookmarked because of curiosity. This request is idiotic.

Comment: Really? Who asks that?

Comment: I know it sounds real stupid, but you have to understand where they are coming from. They have to keep track if something is actually continuing from today thru tomorrow, or if it started tomorrow. here is the link to their developer page: https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference#stop_times_fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well seeing as it's only displaying on the page, you can

firstly get your date from where ever
Let's say `$date = 00:00:00`

```
$exploded_date = explode(":", $date);
```

This takes `$date` and puts it into an array so

`$exploded_date[0] is hh`

`$exploded_date[1] is mm`

`$exploded_date[2] is ss`

Then what you can do is use ltrim() to remove the leading 0 from 00 to 04 `$exploded_date[0]` - This makes it comparable in the if statement I'll do after

```
if($exploded_date[0] <= 4) {

    $exploded_date[0] = ltrim($exploded_date[0], "0");

    $exploded_date[0] = $exploded_date[0]+24;
}
```

Then you can implode the array back together into one string

```
$date = implode(":", $exploded_date);

// if the hour is 00 to 04 it will come out as 24 to 28
// e.g. 24:35:30
echo $date;
```

Despite giving you an answer. It's a silly thing to be doing, but it's not your choice so here you go :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked beautifully DeathByPenguin (please don't die yet, by penguin or otherwise!)

Comment: No problem. Just realised if you use what I've given 05:00:00 may come out as 5:00:00 so I've just put `$exploded_date[0] = ltrim($exploded_date[0], "0");` inside the if statement :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you display something doesn't necesarily has to be the same way you store something.

I don't know how you calculate the times, but assuming you have a start date and time, and some interval, you could calculate the end time as follows:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$start_datetime = new DateTime('2014-11-11T21:00:00');
$next_stop = new DateTime('2014-11-12T02:00:00');

echo $start_datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i'); // 2014-11-11 21:00
echo $next_stop->format('Y-m-d H:i'); // 2014-11-12 02:00

$interval = $start_datetime->diff($next_stop);

// display next stop: 2014-11-11 26:00
echo ($start_datetime->format('Y') + $interval->y) .'-'
     . ($start_datetime->format('m') + $interval->m) .'-'
     . ($start_datetime->format('d') + $interval->d) .' '
     . ($start_datetime->format('H') + $interval->h) .':'
     . ($start_datetime->format('i') + $interval->i);
```

What I'm doing: create the start date (& time) and the datetime of the next stop. With the `DateTime::diff()` function I'm calculating the difference, and then, only for display (!) I add up each year, month, day, hour and minute to the datetime year, month etc. of the next stop.

This way you can still store your dates and times in a way every human being and computer system will understand (because let's be honest; to represent a time as 27:45 PM is quite ridiculous...)

I don't know if you only want the hours to be added up and roll over the 24 hour, or also days in a month etc. It's up to you how you handle these cases. Good luck!